# Has anyone a case implementation for clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I need an implementation of the case macro. The original clojure implementation can't be used since it is kind of using the Java case statement internally.

http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/case

case macro

Usage: (case e & clauses)

I could try to build a macro on my own but it would be all clojure. Maybe there is even a way to use real js functionality.

Has anyone a function or macro for that?

Comment: bsteuber from #clojure suggested the following: `(defmacro case [& args] \`(condp = ~@args))` or simply use condp. This is surely okay but I thought maybe someone can help to build a more js native version.

Comment: That's breaking cross-compatibility in subtle ways, which I wouldn't recommend - consider `(case 'x x 1 y 2)`, for example. Either use `condp` by hand, or make `case` semantically equivalent to the Clojure version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** case has since been added to ClojureScript. Though we cannot give the performance guarantees, the benefits for portability are more important.

case involves a guarantee that's not possible in JavaScript - constant time dispatch on literals. Is there any reason the following doesn't work for you?

```
(condp = x
   ...)
```

Comment: Hello David,

thx for your answer. For my problem (simple char dispatch) condp works fine and I'm glad about the solution.

But I thought someone has an implementation which could possibly be integrated to cljs.

Personally I wouldn't consider the constant dispatch as critical feature but people surely use case, hoping to get performance benefits.
It seems some browsers even provide that http://goo.gl/4UxKs and cljs could maybe benefit from that.

I fear seqs might be a problem, but cljs could print a warning and use some fall back impl.

I fear this discussion should be continued on the ml.

Comment: case was added to Clojure for performance reasons, not semantic ones - otherwise condp = is sufficient and idiomatic. Also, as far as I can tell neither V8 nor JavaScriptCore make switch/case expressions any more efficient than a series of if/else if expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Nice to see the portability becomes more important since this was really a pain point for me. I was writing the app in clojure first then clojurescript. Maybe I could give clojurescript another try now and re-evaluate the problems I had.